# how can i show list view as a horizontal radio list tile?

Tags: flutter, dart, radiobuttonlist

i have a list that was retrieved from the database and i want to show it as a horizontal radio button list. i tried to wrap it with a row but i got errors.

this my code that retrieved them vertically.

```
ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: controller.doc.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return RadioListTile(
                    title: Text(controller.doc[index]['id'],
                        style: TextStyle(color: textColor)),
                    groupValue: tag,
                    value: controller.doc[index]['id'],
                    activeColor: primary,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        tag = value;
                      });
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RadioListTile` is combination between `Radio` widget and `ListTile`.
the ListTile will expand to the maximum width. that will caused error if you make your ListTile with scroll horizontally.

its because the widget failed to hasSize.
if its a must to use `ListTile` , then this is one of solution

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: 4,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, //  <= give specific width
      child: RadioListTile(
        title: const Text("lorem Ipsum",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey)),
        groupValue: false,
        value: false,
        activeColor: Colors.green,
        onChanged: (value) {},
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

other solution is , make your custom radiolistile, eg:

```
Row(
 children:[
   Radio()
   Expanded(child: Text()),
])
```

Comment: it worked than you, however now i have a large space between each button is there is a way to make it smaller?

Comment: its because we use ` width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` .  which is we set the Listtile same as screen width.

Comment: ig you want to set smaller ,  eg: `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5`  =  a half of screen

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: controller.doc.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return RadioListTile(
      title: Text(controller.doc[index]['id'],
          style: TextStyle(color: textColor)),
      groupValue: tag,
      value: controller.doc[index]['id'],
      activeColor: primary,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          tag = value;
        });
      },
    );
  },
);
```

You have to use this `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,`

Comment: are you sure? when i added it the tiles disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Code given above is correct when using RadioListTile horizontally just give it a fixed or calculated width

```
 ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: 4,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return SizedBox(
          width: 350 //  <= give specific width
          child: RadioListTile(
            title: const Text("lorem Ipsum",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey)),
            groupValue: false,
            value: false,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            onChanged: (value) {},
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```